# Does Gradle / javacard plugin support the build of two applets dependency in a multi-project gradle build?

Tags: gradle, javacard

Does gradle mechanism or specifically its javacard plugin has a way to express the dependency wherein the build of one `*.cap` depends on another project's `.exp`.

I googled and found [this PR](https://github.com/fidesmo/gradle-javacard/issues/19) where it seems the feature I am looking for is not yet supported by the plugin.

Currently, the way I build is by: `./gradlew proj01:convertJavacard proj02:convertJavacard`. Wherein, I have to specify first the `proj01:convertJavacard` because it produced the `.exp` file needed by `proj02`. Currently, this works.

I asked here because I want to instead do the elegant-looking: `./gradlew convertJavacard`.

In `proj02/build.gradle` I tried the below relevant section to express the dependency to `proj01`:

```
javacard {
    cap {
        dependencies {
            javacardExport files(rootDir.absolutePath + '/build/javacard/')
            compile files(rootDir.absolutePath + '/build/classes/java/main/')
            compile project(':proj01')
        }
    }
}
```

It did not produce the `proj01` `.exp` file so the build dependency failed. The `compile project(':proj01')` dependency line seems it tried to do an equivalent of something like:  `./gradlew proj01:assemble` because it produced similar output with no `.exp` file. Hence, `proj02` failed to build.

Any tips on how can I do the build by: `./gradlew convertJavacard` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution that works in a `gradle` way. And although, the `gradle plugin` is unable to resolve properly the dependency between the two javacard projects, the override mechanism of a gradle task allowed me to insert an additional dependency relation.

Here is the relevant portion of `proj02/build.gradle` that did the trick:

```
convertJavacard {
    dependsOn ":proj01:convertJavacard"
}

javacard {
    cap {
        dependencies {
            javacardExport files(rootDir.absolutePath + '/build/javacard/')
            compile files(rootDir.absolutePath + '/build/classes/java/main/')
            compile project(':proj01')
        }
    }
}
```

So in conclusion, the javacard plugin alone is unable to link 2 javacard projects. And the gradle task override mechanism came to the rescue.